# How to find the position a SCNNode will fall to after a force/Impulse was added?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate where a ball will land. Basically the "Ball" gets set in position about 2 feet up where the guy's hand is.

Then I want to take the ball's current position and apply a force/impulse to it which will launch it forward. and before it lands I want to try to predict where the ball is going to hit the ground. Also the ground's height in the scene, vector is at 0 everything position wise.

So basically is it possible to calculate where you ball is going to land?

```
Ball.position = SCNVector3Make(Guy.presentationNode.position.x, Guy.presentationNode.position.y, Guy.presentationNode.position.z)          
var Currentposition = Ball.presentationNode.position
var forceApplyed = SCNVector3(x: 50.0, y: 20.0 , z: 0.0)
var LandingPiont = Currentposition + forceApplyed // Error on this line of code saying "+" cannot be applyed to CGVector
Ball.physicsBody?.applyForce(forceApplyed, atPosition: Ball.presentationNode.position, impulse: true)
```

Comment: I don't know if SceneKit offers a method to do this. However, assuming your `forceApplied` is actually an impulse, I can provide a series of equations to calculate the horizontal displacement. You would have to put them into code.

Comment: That would be amazing if you could. Please post! @bpedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to calculate the horizontal displacement using Equations of Uniform Motion. The value of g is set to a default of 9.8 in SceneKit which means you're in the mks system (meters, kilograms, seconds).

The following assumes up is positive y direction and forward, the direction the ball moves horrizontally, is positive x. Be sure to pay attention to signs for the motion along the y. (The following is not code although it appears formatted that way.)

First find the initial vertical velocity (v0y) due to the impulse along the y:

```
v0y = Jy / m
    m is ball’s mass (in kilograms)
    Jy is impulse along the y  (forceApplied.y)
    (v0y will be negative if Jy is negative)
```

Next find the vertical velocity component when ball reaches ground (vy). Because you're finding a square root, you will get both + and – answers, use the negative value.

```
vy ^2 = v0y ^2  +  2 * g * y
    g is your gravitational constant
    y is ball’s initial height 
    both g and y are negative in your case
    use the negative root, i.e.  vy should be negative
```

Find the time (t) the ball spends in the air:

```
t = (vy – v0y) / g
    remember, vy and g are both negative
```

Now you need the velocity along the x:

```
vx = Jx / m
    Jx is impulse along x  (forceApplied.x)
    m is the ball’s mass
    (the velocity along the x remains constant)
```

Finally, solve for the displacement (x) along the x:

```
x = vx * t
    t is the value you got from the vertical motion equations
```